# Build C++ XPCOM dependency error

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I am building my C++ XPCOM for extension with Gecko sdk 24, but I got below error:

```
Error   15   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__NS_CStringContainerInit2   xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib   
Error   16   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__NS_CStringContainerFinish   xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib   
Error   17   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__NS_CStringContainerInit   xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib   
Error   18   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__NS_GetServiceManager   xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib   
Error   19   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__NS_GetComponentManager   xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib   
Error   20   fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals   ..\..\..\firefoxExtension\xpi\components\gecko24\nsWin32Util.dll
```

Preprocessor:
MOZ_NO_MOZALLOC
XP_WIN
XP_WIN32

Additional Dependency:
xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib

I used to build XPCOM with Gecko 10 and dependency are
nspr4.lib
xpcom.lib
xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib
But I cannot find nspr4.lib and xpcom.lib in Gecko 24, So what's the correct settings for Gecko 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try linking against xul.lib?  Note that this is a temporary workaround, though; upstream is getting pretty downright hostile about binary extensions, and you'll probably have better luck doing things via JS-ctypes where possible.  Haven't tested that against nomozalloc, though; not sure how well that will work.

Comment: Yes, your workaround really help build successfully. This XPCOM interact with Windows native API, so it is hard to rewrite in JS.

Comment: You should be OK with v.25 too, be ready for problems with 26:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190810/firefox-26-c-addon-xpcom-dependency-error