# Firefox 26 C++ Addon XPCOM dependency error

Tags: c++, windows, firefox-addon, xpcom, xulrunner

I prepare my C++ Firefox addon for the next Firefox - v.26 - but I can't build it with xulrunner-sdk 26 beta (it is OK with the previous major versions). Just as before, I link it against xpcomglue_staticruntime_s.lib, but I've got these errors:

- xpcomglue_staticruntime_s.lib(nsStringAPI.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_PR_sscanf referenced in function "public: __int64 __thiscall nsAString::ToInteger64(enum tag_nsresult *,unsigned int)const " (?ToInteger64@nsAString@@QBE_JPAW4tag_nsresult@@I@Z)
- xpcomglue_staticruntime_s.lib(nsCRTGlue.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_PR_Now referenced in function "void __cdecl NS_MakeRandomString(char *,int)" (?NS_MakeRandomString@@YAXPADH@Z)

I added all other libraries from this SDK (not only xul.lib and mozalloc.lib but also crmf.lib etc.), it doesn't help. Neither works using xpcomglue_s.lib or xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib instead of xpcomglue_staticruntime_s.lib

Now I can build the addon successfuly only if I use xpcomglue.lib or xpcomglue_staticruntime.lib, but then it doesn't work correctly with Firefox - NS_GetServiceManager() fails. There are some linker warnings with these builds.

What settings I need to make it linking against xpcomglue_staticruntime_s.lib or working in other cases?

Platform: MS Windows, MS Visual Studio 2010.

Two details more:

- In previous sdk versions there was nss3.lib and I added it, now it is missing
- I use the default mozilla-config.h and xpcom-config.h, plus MOZILLA_STRICT_API macro

Comment: [File a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi)

Comment: Ok, I filed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=943230
As temporary solution I added nss3.lib from older sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confirmed bug in the SDK. A fix is planned for Mozilla 28 (OMG!) For details watch here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=937005

In meantime I found that I can use nss3.lib from older versions, tested with this one:
http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/25.0.1/sdk/xulrunner-25.0.1.en-US.win32.sdk.zip

Comment: Actually in the v.26 release they fixed it.